# How to add group product into the cart individually?

Tags: php, magento2

I have two simple products associated with a group product at the product description page and have a separate add to cart button with each product.

I want to add these products to the cart individually, but I am unable to. When I press the first product to add to cart button both products are added to the cart. You can check the scenario by the following this [link](https://magento2.petpanic.gr/skuloi/antiparasitika-gia-skulia/ampoules/ampoules-skulou-antiphlebotome-spot-on.html).

This is my **group.phtml** file:

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

/**
 * Grouped product data template
 *
 * @var $block \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\BaseImage
 * @var $block \Magento\GroupedProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Grouped
 */
?>
<?php $block->setPreconfiguredValue(); ?>
<?php $_product = $block->getProduct(); ?>
<?php $_associatedProducts = $block->getAssociatedProducts(); ?>
<?php $_hasAssociatedProducts = count($_associatedProducts) > 0; ?>
<?php $grouped = $_product->load($_product->getId()); ?>                    
<?php $associatedProducts = $grouped->getTypeInstance()->getAssociatedProducts($grouped); ?>

<div class="table-wrapper grouped">
    <table class="table data grouped" id="super-product-table">
        <caption class="table-caption"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Grouped product items') ?></caption>
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="col item" scope="col"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Product Name') ?></th>
            <?php if ($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                <th class="col qty" scope="col"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Qty') ?></th>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </tr>
        </thead>

        <?php if ($_hasAssociatedProducts): ?>
        <?php foreach ($associatedProducts as $_item): ?>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Product Name')) ?>" class="col item">
                    <strong class="product-item-name"><?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?></strong>
                    <?php if ($block->getCanShowProductPrice($_product)): ?>
                        <?php if ($block->getCanShowProductPrice($_item)): ?>
                            <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getProductPrice($_item) ?>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                     <?php endif; ?>
                </td>
                <?php if ($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                <td data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Qty')) ?>" class="col qty">
                <?php if ($_item->isSaleable()) : ?>
                    <div class="control qty">
                         <form data-role="tocart-form" action="<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_item); ?>" method="post"> 
    <?php echo $block->getBlockHtml('formkey')?>
                        <input type="number"
                               name="super_group[<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_item->getId() ?>]"
                               data-selector="super_group[<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_item->getId() ?>]"
                               value="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_item->getQty() * 1 ?>"
                               title="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Qty') ?>"
                               class="input-text qty"
                               data-validate="{'validate-grouped-qty':'#super-product-table'}"
                               data-errors-message-box="#validation-message-box"/>

    <button type="submit" title="Add to Cart" class="addtocart">
           Add to Cart
        </button>

 </form>

                   <!--button type="button" onclick="setLocation('<?php //echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_item) ?>' + 'qty/' + $(this).previous().value)">Add to cart</button-->
                   </div>

                <?php else: ?>
                    <div class="stock unavailable" title="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Availability') ?>">
                        <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Out of stock') ?></span>
                    </div>
                <?php endif; ?>
                </td>
                <td class="addtocart">
                <?php
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$listBlock = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct');
$addToCartUrl =  $listBlock->getAddToCartUrl($_item);
?>
                    <?php /*
                      <form data-role="tocart-form" action="<?php echo $addToCartUrl; ?>" method="post"> 
    <?php echo $block->getBlockHtml('formkey')?>
        <button type="submit" title="Add to Cart" class="addtocart">
           Add to Cart
        </button>

 </form> */ ?>
</td>

                <?php endif; ?>
            </tr>
            <?php if ($block->getCanShowProductPrice($_product)
                && $block->getCanShowProductPrice($_item)
                && trim($block->getProductPriceHtml(
                    $_item,
                    \Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\TierPrice::PRICE_CODE
                ))): ?>
                <tr class="row-tier-price">
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <?= $block->getProductPriceHtml(
                            $_item,
                            \Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\TierPrice::PRICE_CODE
                        ) ?>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </tbody>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        <?php else: ?>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="unavailable"
                    colspan="<?php if ($_product->isSaleable()): ?>4<?php else : ?>3<?php endif; ?>">
                    <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('No options of this product are available.') ?>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </table>
</div>
<div id="validation-message-box"></div>
```